# Perforce Visual Studio open from source control error

Tags: perforce

I have an existing perforce solution with multiple projects that a former employee checked in (not sure if it was checked in/added with VS or not) and when I try to open the solution in Visual Studio 2010 via the scc plugin I get the following error:

What is the fix for this?

"The project you have chosen cannot be correctly opened from source control.

You are attempting to open a solution or project that was not added to source control using Microsoft Visual Studio. Microsoft Visual Studio supports opening solutions from source control only when they are added (or bound) using Microsoft Visual Studio.
The user who initially added the solution must use the Change Source Control command to bind the solution to source control in its current location."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the solution in VS 2010.

Then open File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control

In this dialog you can bind the solution to the p4 server.